# Vertex's geometry and normal in 3D polygon mesh

Tags: 3d, image-processing

I am following [a papre](http://webee.technion.ac.il/~ayellet/Ps/12-LST.pdf) suggesting a vertex descriptor based on normal and geometry among other features (2.1. Vertex distinctness).

I could not understand how do you extract a vertex's information such as a normal or shape from object that is similar to a simple 3-D point. I can see the definition of a vertex in [polygon mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh) includes color, texture and normal and I can definitely understand how I can generate a 3D point cloud with information regarding color and texture. I am still lost on the definition of a normal or geometry of a point.

Is there an intuitive description of these characteristics?

Comment: The author's are computing per-vertex features, using e.g. the neighbours of a given point in the mesh. For instance, the normal vector at a point is the estimated normal at that point based on an approximation of the underlying surface. Is there something in particular confusing you?

Comment: Yes, given a point cloud (not a fully defined mesh), what is the definition for a vertex's normal?  A normal is supposed to be perpendicular to the surface, only in a point cloud, it is my understanding that there is no surface. How can we speak in terms of normals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an unstructured (meshless) point cloud $P=\{p_i\}$, estimating the normals of $P$ usually requires an estimation of the underlying surface. That is, it is assumed that the $p_i$'s are samples from some underlying true manifold.

Here's one simple approach to estimating the normal $n_i$ at $p_i$. Fix $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and denote $N_k(p)$ as the $k$ nearest neighbours of $p$.
Compute the centroid
$$
q_i = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{p\,\in\, N_k(p_i)} p
$$
and local covariance matrix
$$
\Sigma(p_i) = \frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{p\,\in\, N_k(p_i)} (p-q_i)(p-q_i)^T
$$
and then the eigenvectors $v_j(p_i)=\text{eigvec}_j(\Sigma(p_i))$.
Then, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $n_i = v_3(p_i)$. The two tangent vectors to the estimated surface are then $T_{i}^1=v_1(p_i)$ and $T_{i}^2=v_2(p_i)$.

Obviously, this approach has problems when two far-away parts of the surface (in terms of geodesic distance) are near each other in the ambient space, or when the sampling is too sparse or uneven.

See also [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php).
For more sophisticated approaches, see, for example, [*Estimating Surface Normals in Noisy Point Cloud Data* by Mitra and Nguyen](http://vecg.cs.ucl.ac.uk/Projects/SmartGeometry/normal_est/paper_docs/normal_estimation_socg_03.pdf).